# Search through datagridview not working - System.NullReferenceException error

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying to run a search through column 2 (data type: number) on my datagridview but keep getting the following error message:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in SpeedyRent.exe
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

The error is being thrown at `if (!string.Equals(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString(), driverNo.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))`

[image]

What is it that I'm doing wrong? I've included my code below:

```
    void driverSearch()
    {
        CurrencyManager manager = (CurrencyManager)BindingContext[dataGridView1.DataSource];
        manager.SuspendBinding();
        bool shouldNotFilter = string.IsNullOrEmpty(driverNo.Text);
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (shouldNotFilter)
            {
                row.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                if (!string.Equals(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString(), driverNo.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    row.Visible = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    row.Visible = true;
                }
            }
        }
        manager.ResumeBinding();
    }

    private void driverNo_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        driverSearch();
    }

    private void driverNo_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        driverSearch();
    }

    private void driverNo_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        driverSearch();
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any rows that have less than 3 cells or have a null value? `row.Cells[2].Value.ToString()` could be the source of the problem if there are less than 3 cells (i.e. 2 doesn't exist), or if the value of the cell is null.

Comment: Yeah, are you sure you didn't mean `Cells[1]`?

Comment: I've just tried Cells[1] - getting the same error message

Comment: well you could tell us what line the error is thrown on.  Or even debug that line and figure out what is null.

Comment: The error is being thrown at `if (!string.Equals(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString(), driverNo.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))`

Comment: apply a break point and check in Quick Watch the total `count of row cells`. Or you can check for null in your code as well.

Comment: @HassanNisar it doesn't work

Comment: @methuselah what it says? you can add this check too `row.Cells[1] != null`

Comment: @HassanNisar - where should I add it?

Comment: try this: `if (row.Cells[1] != null && !string.Equals(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString(), driverNo.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50971/discussion-between-methuselah-and-hassan-nisar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this block in foreach loop:

```
if (shouldNotFilter)
{
     row.Visible = true;
}
else
{
    if(row.Cells[1].Value == null)
    {
       row.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
         if (!string.Equals(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString(), driverNo.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
         {
              row.Visible = false;
         }
         else
         {
              row.Visible = true;
         }
    }
}
```